# How can I reduce the contextily source footer at the bottom of a cartopy GeoAxes?

Tags: geopandas, cartopy, contextily

I'm attempting to plot a contextily basemap onto one of my cartopy GeoAxes, but the problem is the source footer at the bottom is HUGE. Is there any way to decrease its size? Thanks!

This is how I simply add it to my axes:

```
import contextily as ctx

ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs01[:,0], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ctx.add_basemap(ax2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set option `attribution_size` in `ctx.add_basemap`, for example:-

```
ctx.add_basemap(ax2, attribution_size=6)
```